# Trying to understand Mutability. Modify Reference vs. modify Object

Tags: rust, mutability

I am trying to understand mutability.

When I declare a variable in Rust with

```
let mut a = String::from("Foo");
```

I can modify the Object, e.g.:

```
a.push_str("Bar");
```

Or assign a new Object, e.g:

```
a = String::from("Bar");
```

When I declare a variable without 'mut'

```
let a = String::from("Foo");
```

I can neither modify the Object nor assign a new Object.

So I can either choose to:

1. have a mutable object with a mutable variable
   or
2. have an immutable obejct with an immutable variable

I wonder if it is possible to declare vaiables so that

1. the object is immutable, but the variable is mutable and can be assigned to a different object
   or
2. the object is mutable, but the variable is immutable and cannot be assigned to a different object.

I read the [chapter about mutability in the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html)
but couln't find any information which could help me further.

Comment: For 1. you can use types that offer interior mutability: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html. For 2, I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we need to make an important distinction:

In `let mut`, `mut` is a property of the *binding*, i.e. the variable. The variable and everything it contains can be mutated, but only as long as it contains it. We can transfer the content to another variable, and then mutability will be decided by the new one:

```rust
let v = String::from("Foo");
// Cannot mutate `v`.
v.clear(); // ERROR
v = String::new(); // ERROR

let mut new_v = v;
new_v.clear(); // OK
new_v = String::new(); // OK
```

In contrast, mutability of *references* (`&` and `&mut`) is a property of the value. Even if we transfer ownership, shared references cannot be mutated (unless they contain interior mutability).

Now, I can answer your questions:

> the object is immutable, but the variable is mutable and can be assigned to a different object or

Yes, if we make the variable a shared reference:

```rust
let mut v = &String::from("Foo");
v.clear(); // ERROR
let other = String::new();
v = &other; // OK
```

> the object is mutable, but the variable is immutable and cannot be assigned to a different object.

Yes, if an immutable variable contains a mutable reference:

```rust
let v = &mut String::from("Foo");
v.clear(); // OK
let mut other = String::new();
v = &mut other; // ERROR
```

Another way to satisfy (2), as already said, is using [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html):

```rust
let v = std::cell::RefCell::new(String::from("Foo"));
v.borrow_mut().clear(); // OK
v = String::new(); // ERROR
```

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation.
It took me a while to understand it, but now I can follow your examples.

Answer (score 0):

In Rust, You can have [interior mutability](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html) where the binding is immutable, but the object is mutable.

If the binding however is mutable then the object is also mutable.

You can create a mutable reference to an immutable T `mut &T`, this will allow you to mutate the binding, but not the object.